# Passing parameters from mount to kernel module

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel, kernel-module, mount

Is there any way to pass parameter from mount system call to kernel module.
Like mount -t ext2 abc=/Dir/ target.

Here i want to pass parameter abc from mount to kernel module.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can only have `mount` do something for you if you develop your own filesystem.

In that case, when you call `register_filesystem` you need to give it a `file_system_type` which contains a `.mount` field. Mount is a function with this prototype:

```
struct dentry *some_mount(struct file_system_type *fs_type,
    int flags, const char *dev_name, void *data);
```

You can access data passed with `-o` to mount via the `data` parameter.

---

If all you want to do is pass some data from userland to your module, a far simpler way would be to use `module_param`:

```
static char *abc = "";
module_param(abc, charp, 0000);
MODULE_PARM_DESC(abc, "Some string that you give to insmod");
```

Comment: Hey can you exactly tell how to get -o arguments. Like they get stored in string and we have to substring from it or something else ?